# Want show spinner until all four component get data from API

Tags: reactjs

I React JS
There is parent component on that 4 child component. I want show spinner until all four component get data from API.

Answer (score 0):

If each component has to call the api and where
If it's in the parent component with 4 api call
use a state to display a loader, Promise.all(your 4 api call).then(() => setLoading(false))

If each child call the api:
add an onLoad props to your child allowing to notify the parent when it's done
when the 4 onLoad have been executed, remove the loader

Or there are a lot of other ways to do that, provide some code if you want some help

But if the parent component has to display the loader and you have 4 api call, I guess the parent should handle the api call, it would be easier to read